Infinispan Replicated Cache problem when 1 node goes down in clustering
I am using Infinispan replicated cache with a three-node active cluster and my application server is JBoss. My TPS is 200 . When one of the nodes goes down, I am unable to retrieve some messages that were cached by active nodes at the moment the one node went down, causing inconsistencies.
Please guide me on the reason for this occurrence and how to prevent it. Also, I would like to know if there is a setting to catch exceptions when replicated cache encounters issues.
<cache-container name="qcachename" statistics-enabled="true">
    <transport/>
     <replicated-cache name="cachename" statistics-enabled="true">
          <expiration lifespan="60000"/>
     </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>

I am expecting that in the event of one node going down, if there is a disruption in the message replication mechanism, an exception should be thrown, or the message should be successfully put into the active cache without any issues, allowing the retrieval of the message from the cache.
It seems that clustering has been properly configured because message replication is occurring.
Consider this scenario, where power is lost in one of the nodes, causing the application server to shut down completely. Now, imagine that power is restored. Right at the moment When the application server starts up and my application is deploying, a message is put and immediately removed in two other nodes. It appears that because the third application server has not fully started and the replication process cannot be completed on all three servers, it needs to retrieve the message stored in the cache of the two nodes without any hint, creating inconsistency for our application.

I assume this is embedded mode. Is the cluster forming correctly?

I answered your question in the last paragraph

What version is this using? The way it works upon joining is that the joining node will not be used for data reads only writes.
Also to note that while a write operations is currently being processed the data reads can be seen with the previous value or the new value, are you sure this is not what you are seeing?

My version:12.02, and my main issue is at the moment of deploying node3(right at the moment, when jboss started and my app is deploying) put and immediately remove occure in other nodes(remove without my request), why removed without my request?
I used transaction in my replicated setting and seems my issue is fixed, did adding transactio has affect?

this is my transaction setting:


